# T-SQL using 2 parameters and isNull

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, isnull

Could someone help me to understand the logic of this query (T-SQL in SQL Server 2014) in simple way?

```
Select 
    c.ContractID 
From 
    dba.contract as c 
Inner Join 
    dba.Person as r on (c.ContractID = r.ContractID 
                        and IsNull(isPrimary, 0) = 1)
```

The part that I dont understand is the `isNull(isPrimary, 0) = 1`.

What does that mean? Btw `isPrimary` is one of the columns in `dba.person`

Thank you so much!

Comment: This function return first argument, if it is not null, in other cases you will have second argument.

Comment: IsNull() serves no purpose here.  could be  ... and isPrimary=1  because null is not equal to 1

Comment: It's handling NULL values in equality comparisons. It does the equivalent of and(isPrimary = 1 or isPrimary IS NULL).

Comment: Suggested reading: Good information about `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` is at SQL Server Pro [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull) and MSDN Blogs [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx).

Comment: thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
isNull(isPrimary, 0) = 1
```

isNull is a function of SQL which is used to verify null variable
and above snippet describe as if `isPrimary` variable is null then replace this null value with 0. the purpose of this method to handle null pointer exception.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The `IS_NULL` function is only replacing the value of `isPrimary` to 0, in case the `isPrimary` is equal to `NULL`.

Your check is only true when `isPrimary` is not null (because if it is, it will be replaced by 0) AND `isPrimary` = 1.

```
SELECT c.contractid 
FROM   dba.contract AS c 
       INNER JOIN dba.person AS r ON (c.contractid = r.contractid AND isprimary = 1)
WHERE isprimary IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: If `IsPrimary` is NULL, then the code will substitute that with a `0` (not a `1` as you mention in your first sentence)

Comment: thank you for your help! is it possible to use more than 2 where clauses to replace it?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the answer for that,  but I do not understand why would you want to replace it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch how it works, you can create table in your database:

```
use [your_database_name];
create table dbo.test_table
(
    t int null
);

insert into dbo.test_table 
values (0), (1), (2), (NULL);

select t, isnull(t, 0) as function_result
from dbo.test_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample script for you to understand IsNull(isPrimary, 0) = 1 condition gives 
the result and helps in handling Null pointer exception.

---

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE (Id int, isPrimary varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @table
SELECT 1,1001  UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1002  UNION ALL
SELECT 3,NULL  UNION ALL
SELECT 4,1004
SELECT Id,ISNULL(isPrimary,0) UIdnum FROM @table

SELECT * FROM @table WHERE ISNULL(isPrimary,0)=1

SELECT * FROM @table WHERE ISNULL(isPrimary,0)=0
```